# The relationship between outer measures and smallest coverings

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Recall that if $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ is an algebra and $\mu_{0}:\mathcal{A} \to [0,\infty]$ is a premeasure on $\mathcal{A}$ then we can define the outer measure $\mu^{*}$ for any set $E\subset X$ by:
\begin{equation}
\mu^{*}(E)=\inf \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu_{0}(A_{j}) : A_{j} \in \mathcal{A}, E \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_{j} \right\}
\end{equation}
Now suppose that we know that $\mu^{*}(E)$ exists. Let $\{B_{k}\}_{k= 1}^{\infty}$ be a countable sequence of coverings of the set $E$ such that each $B_{k}$ can be written as the countable union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$; i.e. $B_{k}$ can be written:
\begin{equation}
B_{k}=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_{j}^{k}, \text{ for all $k$, where $A_{j}^{k} \in \mathcal{A}$}
\end{equation}
My question is the following: can we re-write the definition of $\mu^{*}(E)$ above as:
\begin{equation}
\mu^{*}(E)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu_{0}(A_{j}) ,\text {where } A_{j} \in B,  B= \inf_{k\geq 1} B_{k}
\end{equation}
i.e. is the outer measure for any set $E \subset X$ equal to the sum of the measures of the sets $A_{j} \in B$ that comprise the smallest covering of $E$?

I believe this is true by the monotonicity of the premeasure $\mu_{0}$, so that the smallest covering must also have the smallest sum of measures over the sets that comprise it. However, I am using this result in a proof and would like to verify that it is true.

If it is true please provide a proof. If it is not true please provide a counterexample.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $B = \inf_{k \geq 1} B_k$ and by $A_j \in B$, respectively? Also, I do not understand the final displayed formula. Did you forget an "$\inf$" on the right-hand side?

Comment: @PhoemueX I want $B$ to be the smallest covering of $E$, and I want $A_{j}$ to be any set that comprises the covering $B$; i.e. so that I can write $B$ as a union of all the $A_{j}$'s. I did not forget an $\inf$, my question is about whether I can move it inside the brackets and take the $\inf$ over the coverings of $E$.

Comment: On the right-hand side of your last equation, you have a set. A number cannot equal a set, so I still think that you forgot an $\inf$. Also in general there is not a "smallest" covering. Think of the algebra generated by the family of half-open intervals $[a,b)$ with $a \leq b$ and $E = \Bbb{Q}$ (and the usual Lebesgue measure, i.e. length of intervals as premeasure). In this case, there is no "smallest" cover, since this would have to satisfy $\sum_j \mu(A_j) = 0 = \mu^\ast (\Bbb{Q})$, but any nontrivial interval $I$ has $\mu(I) > 0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I see what you mean and I have revised the notation  slightly, but you provide a good counterexample which may make my revision mute. Question: If what you say is true, then what exactly are we taking the $\inf$ over in the definition of an outer measure? If the $\inf$ is over the sum then what do we choose to be the $A_{j}$'s in the  definition of an outer measure for your example where $E=\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: For example, let $(x_n)_n$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb{Q}$. Then, for arbitrary $k$, let $A_j^k := [x_j, x_j + \frac{1/k}{2^j} )$. Then $\sum_j \mu(A_j^k) \leq \sum_j \frac{1/k}{2^j} \leq 100/k \to 0$. The point here is that although you can get "arbitrarily small" coverings, there is no "smallest" one.

Comment: @PhoemueX I am still having some confusion. You say that you can have arbitrarily small coverings but that there is no smallest one.But is this not taken into account by the definition of the infimum? In particular, we know that all coverings are bounded below by the set that they cover. So why is the infimum over all coverings not defined? In your example above it seems that the infimum of all coverings of $\mathbb{Q}$ (of the kind of covers you provided) is the set $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \{x_{n}\}$ (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}$ itself). Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with it, except that $\{x_n\}$ is **not** contained in the algebra generated by the half open intervals. Hence, $\mu_0 (\{x_n\})$ is not defined a priori.